# Web download of vcruntime140 with wix burn

Tags: wix, burn

I want to use the WiX bootstrapper `burn` to automatically download and install the vcruntime140 package (Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015) if it is required.

It's trivially easy to do this for the .NET frameworks:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>
  ...
</Chain>
```

but I can't find an equivalent for the vcruntime packages. (Is that because there isn't one, or am I just typing the wrong keywords into Google?)

Just to be clear: I do not want to include the package with my installer. It must be a web download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no PackageGroupRef for the redist as for .net.

But there is 3 other options:

1. Add a redist exe in your chain. (Not good for you)
2. Use a [redist c++ merge module](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html) inside one of your msi's.
3. Try to write your own [web download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) as .net does. Here is a sample of the .net web download. The full file can be found in the source code of wix by the name "NetFx46.wxs"

```
<Fragment>
 <PropertyRef Id="WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED" />
 <Property Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
 <SetProperty Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" Value="1" After="AppSearch">
   WIXNETFX4RELEASEINSTALLED >= "#$(var.NetFx46MinRelease)"
 </SetProperty>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx46Web" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=558772" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx46WebDetectCondition" Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx46MinRelease)" Overridable="yes" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx46WebInstallCondition" Value="" Overridable="yes" />
<WixVariable Id="NetFx46WebPackageDirectory" Value="redist\" Overridable="yes" />

<PackageGroup Id="NetFx46Web">
  <ExePackage
      InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx46FullLog].html&quot;"
      RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx46FullLog].html&quot;"
      UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx46FullLog].html&quot;"
      PerMachine="yes"
      DetectCondition="!(wix.NetFx46WebDetectCondition)"
      InstallCondition="!(wix.NetFx46WebInstallCondition)"
      Id="NetFx46Web"
      Vital="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Protocol="netfx4"
      DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=560371"
      LogPathVariable="NetFx46FullLog"
      Compressed="no"
      Name="!(wix.NetFx46WebPackageDirectory)NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe">
    <RemotePayload 
      CertificatePublicKey="52868DFCA6E3AF2632389E6C1EE7D0468D3797D0" 
      CertificateThumbprint="3BDA323E552DB1FDE5F4FBEE75D6D5B2B187EEDC" 
      Description="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Setup" 
      Hash="480CA134B9E3F2437DF10719D5A8C77DDEC0A4F1" 
      ProductName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6" 
      Size="1497400" 
      Version="4.6.81.0" />
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

Comment: Just to note that [Microsoft no longer recommend the use of merge modules for the v140 runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, here's my final solution.

Right-click on the bootstrapper project References in Visual Studio and add a reference to WixUtilExtension.

Add `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` as an attribute to the top level `Wix` element.

Add to the `<Chain>` element:

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="vcredist_vc140"/>
```

Add as a child of the `<Wix>` element:

```
<Fragment>
  <!-- vcredist 2015 x86 -->
  <util:ProductSearch
      Id="VCREDIST_140_x86"
      UpgradeCode="65E5BD06-6392-3027-8C26-853107D3CF1A"
      Result="version"
      Variable="VCREDIST_140_x86"/>
  <PackageGroup Id="vcredist_vc140">
    <ExePackage
        Id="vc140"
        Cache="yes"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Permanent="yes"
        Vital="yes"
        Compressed="no"
        DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615459"
        Name="vcredist_vc140"
        InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
        DetectCondition="(VCREIST_140_x86 &gt;= v14.0.24215)">
      <RemotePayload
          Description="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24215"
          ProductName="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24215"
          Size="14456872"
          Version="14.0.24215.1"
          Hash="72211BD2E7DFC91EA7C8FAC549C49C0543BA791B" />
    </ExePackage>
  </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

`UpgradeCode` came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35889484) and is specific to v14.0.24215 of the vcredist installer. This is how the bootstrapper decides whether it is already installed.

`Compressed="no"` tells the installer not to include the file in the installer itself (since we want to download it from the web).

`DownloadUrl` is a direct URL to the downloadable installer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34898969).

`RemotePayload Description` is the text of the installer's Description resource and likewise `ProductName`. (It appears that the text does *not* have to match the text in the resources. `ProductName` is the description shown in the bootstrapper's progress dialog.)

`Size` is the size in bytes.
`Hash` is found with the Powershell command `get-filehash -algorithm SHA1 .\vc_redist.x86.exe`.

I hope this helps someone.