# Default minimum required version of Windows Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Good day!
I use Wix v3.11 to create MSI, and my project uses merge module for VCRedist.
After getting the warning that I should "*set the Package/@InstallerVersion attribute **to 301 or greater to merge this merge module***" I noticed that by default WiX sets Package/@InstallerVersion to 200. Why? Modern versions of Windows come with Windows Installer 4.5 and greater (here is the [table from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/released-versions-of-windows-installer)).

Comment: Check the wix documentation [here](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) It's explaining why. For your installer you can set `InstallerVersion="301"`

Comment: I believe the version is set as low as possible to ensure the MSI can be installed on as many systems as possible - until there is a technical reason not to allow it, which is exactly what you have discovered with that merge module. A higher version is required. I would set the version to what is suggested in that error message. What VCRedist version is this?

Comment: VCRedist ships libraries for VC140 toolset, which corresponds to MSVS 2015.

Comment: One trick is to put such merge modules in a separate setup to avoid them being part of your main setup. Helps corporate deployment. Some prefer to [download the run-time on-demand via a Burn bootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720958/web-download-of-vcruntime140-with-wix-burn) because the run-time they bundle in the setup gets outdated and hence just bloats the download and complicates their setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is `200` because WiX v3.x still views Windows XP as a viable target operating system. Now, I know Windows XP is a menace to the internet and it is easy to argue that support for Windows XP should be dropped. However, the WiX Toolset doesn't drop platforms easily so `200` remains the baseline for WiX v3.x.

In WiX v4.0 the open question whether the minimum should move to `500`, as Windows 7 is the minimum (barely) supported Windows.

Comment: I've experienced issues trying to install modern software on a fully patched win7.   I barely test on it anymore unless asked and don't touch XP period.